# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.4 PlayOnLinux Wine program cannot be alt-tabbed otherwise I can't get back into it

Tags: 14.04, gnome, playonlinux

I have Banished installed through PLayOnLinux and the game starts and everything seems to be working fine, but I can't seem to ALT-TAB back into the game?

Answer (score 1):

Not all games work with "Alt+tab" well, which is true for native Windows either, but unfortunately I can't remember the technical reasons for that. Still, there're a few workarounds you can try:

1. *(preferable, but may not work)* try to run a game on a separate desktop, and instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> just switch between desktops.
2. Run `winecfg` go to tab "Graphics", and set checkbox "emulate a virtual desktop". AFAIK this always works, but may hurt performance.
3. Open a separate xserver with `xinit wine ./game.exe -- :1 vt8`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> to switch between them. Note: this may not work well with multiplayer as usually graphical apps are freezes upon switching servers, so upon switching from the game, it may lose connection. Also, as I remember, xinit needs some configuring by default, at least something with sound.